# Django server url alias

Tags: python, django, alias

How can I set an alias in Django Server, for example :

```
http://10.179.146.45:8080/en/
```

to be

```
http://my_name/en/
```

I run this server without apache and without mod_wsgi.

Comment: Are you asking about how to make `http://my_name/en/` in your web browser go to your Django server (`runserver` or whatever) running on `10.179.146.45` at port `8080`? Also, do you need everyone in the world to be able to do this, everyone in your company/organisation/team, or just yourself?

Comment: and add an entry in /etc/hosts for 10.179.146.45 myname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the host name and port for the Django development server.

```
$ manage.py runserver my_name:8080
```